# Is it necessary to quote command substitutions during variable assignment in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Nearly everywhere I've read, including Google's bash scripting style guide mention to necessity of quoting command substitutions (except when specifically desired of course).

I understand the when/where/why of quoting command substitutions during general use. For example: `echo "$(cat <<< "* useless string *")"` rather than `echo $(...)`

However for variable assignments specifically, I have seen so many examples as such:
`variable="$(command)"`

Yet I have found no instances where `variable=$(command)` is not equivalent.

`variable="$(echo "*")"` and `variable=$(echo "*")` both set the value to '*'.

Can anyone give any situations where leaving the substitution unquoted during variable assigment would actually cause a problem?

Comment: Good question! I did many tests and it looks like they are exactly the same, no difference.

Comment: I think issue he is asking about can occur with $cmd, ${cmd}. In substitution and in If clauses, We need "" there. Please correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell does not perform *word splitting* for variable assignments (it is standardized that way by POSIX and you can rely on it). Thus you do not need double quotes (but you can use them without making the result different) in

```
variable=$(command)   # same as variable="$(command)"
```

However, word-splitting is performed before executing commands, so in

```
echo $(command)
echo "$(command)"
```

the result may be different. The latter keeps all multi-space sequences, while the former makes each word a different argument to echo. It is up to you to decide which is the desired behavior.

Interesting shell quirk: there is one more place where quoting a substitution or not makes no difference, namely the expression in a `case expr in` construct.

```
case $FOO in
  (frob) ...;;
esac
```

is indistinguishable from

```
case "$FOO" in
  (frob) ...;;
esac
```

Comment: That's what this answer says.

Comment: Can you give a link to the exact part of the POSIX standard where this is required? I have trouble finding it.

Comment: @Lucas I would interpret 2.9.1 Simple Commands, #4 in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01: *"Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal prior to assigning the value."* It does not say word-splitting here.

Comment: In `bash`, a parameter expansion used as the argument to the here-string operator is also not subject to word splitting or pathname generation, although bug fixes did not make that a reality until the recent 4.4 release.

Answer (score 4):

When using BASH, those two lines are 100% equivalent:

```
variable="$(command)"
variable=$(command)
```

while these two aren't:

```
echo $(command)
echo "$(command)"
```

Alas, the human brain isn't a computer. It's especially not as reliable when it comes to repeat a job.

So chances are that if you mix styles (i.e. you quote when you use command arguments but you don't quote when you assign a variable), that once in a while, you'll get it wrong.

Worse, once in a while you will want the command result to be expanded into individual words. And the next guy who reads your code will wonder if he's looking at a bug.

Conculsion: Since the first two lines are the same, it's easier on the average brain to always quote `$()` (even when it's not necessary) to make sure you always quote when you have to.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then as to why it is recommended so frequently... When I first started writing shell scripts I took to quoting as a general rule. Now that I'm much more familiar with it I just try to eliminate anything redundant or unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

Testing with so many different commands, it is the same. Can't find a difference.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. And to see a difference try `echo $(echo -e "hello\nworld")` against `echo "$(echo -e "hello\nworld")"`